# whats the biggest number that is smaller than FLT_EPSILON?

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-accuracy

In C using float.h I wonder how can I find the largest number that if I add to 1 the answer will remain 1.

i.e 1 + x = 1 how to find x?

Comment: @KerrekSB EPS/2 may satisfy the condition, but it's not necessarily the largest

Answer (score 8):

If you want "the biggest number that is smaller than FLT_EPSILON":

```
x = nextafterf(FLT_EPSILON, 0)
```

If you want the biggest number `x` such that `1.0f + x == 1.0f`, then the answer depends on the rounding mode, but in the default rounding mode, it's simply `FLT_EPSILON/2`.

However, things aren't quite so simple. Because of the way round-to-nearest rounds to the *even* neighbor on ties, you have `1.0f + FLT_EPSILON/2 == 1.0f`, but:

```
(1.0f+FLT_EPSILON) + FLT_EPSILON/2 != (1.0f+FLT_EPSILON)
```

So you may instead want to use the slightly smaller value of `x`:

```
x = nextafterf(FLT_EPSILON/2, 0)
```

This will ensure that `y+x == y` for any `y >= 1.0`.

Comment: The question uses the informal and wrong definition of FLT_EPSILON as the smallest float that can be added to 1.0f to obtain a value other than 1.0f. The correct definition is the difference between the successor of 1.0f and 1.0f. For this correct definition, your candidate `nextafterf(FLT_EPSILON, 0)` does not have the property that  1.0f + candidate == 1.0f. This is not your fault but the question's.

Comment: Yes, I see now that the question is inconsistent. I answered the subject line, but that doesn't give a correct answer for the body of the message.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on rounding modes. Here's a simple example. Suppose our precision is 4 bits, and we have some sort of IEEE754 representation. So the value 1 is stored as 1.0000 × 2<sup>0</sup>. The next bigger number is 1.0001 × 2<sup>0</sup>, and the machine epsilon ε is defined as the difference between the two, which is 0.0001 × 2<sup>0</sup> = 1.0000 × 2<sup>−4</sup>. Now:

- ε / 2 = 1.0000 × 2<sup>−5</sup> = 0.00001, and
- ε / 4 = 1.0000 × 2<sup>−6</sup> = 0.000001.

When you add one of the two to 1, the numbers are first rewritten for the power 2<sup>0</sup> and rounded to 4 digits after the separator. The surviving mantissa of ε / 4 is surely 0.0000, while the surviving mantissa of ε / 2 is either 0.0000 or 0.0001, depending on whether you round up or down.

As long as the effective resulting mantissa is 0.0000, you can add the number to 1 without changing its value.

(The actual precisions are 23+1, 52+1 and 64 for single, double and extended double precision floats.)